# How to build AWS services using Terraform with Bamboo

Tags: bamboo, terraform-provider-aws

Can someone mention the steps in setting up the CI/CD pipeline for creating AWS services using Terraform in Bamboo

Comment: Hi Goutham and welcome to SO, how is it different from any other Terraform script?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to create a build plan which looks as follows:

```
STAGE: Plan
    JOB: Plan
        TASK: Script, terraform init -input=false
        TASK: Script, terraform validate -input=false
        TASK: Script, terraform plan -out=tfplan -input=false
STAGE: Apply
    JOB: Apply
        TASK: Script, terraform apply -input=false tfplan
```

The 'Apply' stage should be configured to be a 'Manual stage', meaning it needs manual approval before it will run. This allows to review the created Terraform plan in the first stage before applying it on your infrastructure. The plan itself can be linked to, and trigger on the repository with your Terraform specifications.

In terms of connecting with AWS, you can provide the required Terraform variables as environment variables in your scripts, which themselves refer to regular bamboo variables. For example:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID ="${bamboo.AwsAccessKeyId}"

terraform plan ...
```

In terms of fetching these variable values from AWS, you might be interested in this plugin: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1221965/secret-managers-for-bamboo (note that I am affiliated).

Comment: Wondering why this is not possible in a deployment project. I want to run a Terraform project for production and test environment. Or would I need to create an artifact from Plan stage and use it in the deployment project?

Comment: @Michael yes in the build/test stage you could run the plan, and grab -out=tfplan as an artifact.  Other option is to just grap the artifact that needs to be deployed, and then update the terraform in deployment to push the artifact out.